# Can you configure IPython Notebook to show a CellToolbar on load?

Tags: javascript, ipython

Can you configure IPython Notebook to show a CellToolbar on load? If not, is there a IPython JS API call that can be made on notebook load to show a particular toolbar? I'm poking through the JS API but can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `custom.js`, on the notebook app loaded event or notebook loaded event (depending on what you wish):

```
// Replace "Default "By whichever preset you like.
IPython.CellToolbar.activate_preset("Default"); 
IPython.CellToolbar.global_show();
```

This Api is neither stable, nor documented.

Comment: Thanks. The global_show() after the activate is the part I was missing.